How to add a value to a HTML tag like a p tag using javascript
I'm trying to create a BMI calculator that displays a user's BMI once they submit their height and weight. But the results won't display in the p tag.


let myHeight = document.getElementById("height");
let myWeight = document.getElementById("weight");
let answer = document.getElementsByClassName("result");

function BMIcalc() {
  if (myHeight.value === "" || myWeight.value === "") {
    alert("Please fill in your height and weight!");
  } else{
    const BMI = myWeight.value / myHeight.value**2;
    answer.value = BMI;
  }
});
<form>
  <label for="height">Please input your height:</label>
  <input id="height" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="height">
  <label for="weight">Please input your weight:</label>
  <input id="weight" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="weight">
  <button onclick="BMIcalc" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>

<h3>Your BMI is: </h3>
<p class="result"></p>



The answer won't display in the p tag
However, if I use console.log(), the result is displayed meaning the function is working correctly. But I need to be able to show the result to the user.
I've also tried using:
let myHeight = document.getElementById("height");

let myWeight = document.getElementById("weight");

function BMIcalc() {
  if (myHeight.value === "" || myWeight.value === "") {
    alert("Please fill in your height and weight!");
  } else{
    const BMI = myWeight.value / myHeight.value**2;
    const answer = BMI;
    document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerText = answer;
  }
}

Nothing works

Only <input>-like tags have a "value" attribute. You're looking for .innerText or .innerHTML to set the content of your <p> tag.

Also note: getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection, not a single element.

I sure hope you aren't using h3 because you like the way it renders the text and instead are using it to further sub-divide an existing h2.

remember that everything you get from input elements are strings, so you need to parseFloat those before you can do math with them. Also remember that paragraphs are not form elements, they don't have a .value property. And of course: getElementsByClassName returns a list of elements, not "just one". If you want just one, use document.querySelector with a query selector that's specific to your paragraph element.

adding to the previous points your onclick="BMIcalc" should also be "BMIcalc()"

Thanks for the feedback. I'm learning as I go, and I've implemented all these and it finally works.

Some things that you'll want to address:

Remember that everything you get from input elements are strings, so you need to parseFloat those before you can do math with them (and always parseFloat rather than parseInt, as JS has no distinct integer number type, and the parseInt function can do really unexpected things if you don't know it takes a second argument that specifies which base to parse)
Also remember that paragraphs are not form elements, they don't have a .value property, they have a .textContent/.innerText property like all regular (non-void) DOM elements.
Very importantly: getElementsByClassName returns a live HTMLCollection, not "just one element". If you want to specifically select just your one element, either give it an id and get it that way, or use document.querySelector with a query selector that's specific to your paragraph element.
And finally: if you don't need to pack up a form and send it off to a server, you don't need a form tag, and your button doesn't need to submit anything.

With a bonus fact: HTML elements with an id attribute are automatically availabe on the JS side by that name (provided the id string is a valid JS variable name). So <input id="height".... will automatically be a variable called height on the JS side, no need to find it in your DOM. (But of course, if you're doing this, remember to use id names that don't conflict with built-in JS global variable names!)
So, working all that in:


// By giving everything id attributes, we don't need to search
// for any of the elements involved in the logic we're coding:

calculate.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  BMI.textContent = ``;
  const h = parseFloat(height.value);
  const w = parseFloat(weight.value);

  // Note that parseFloat does not test if the entire input "was
  // a number", it only parses things up to "when they stop being
  // a number", So we need to check whether the conversion result
  // actually matches the input. If not, that's bad input. So,
  // turn the number back into a string, and see if it matches:
  if (`${h}` !== height.value || `${w}` !== weight.value) {
    return alert(`Please fill in your height in cm and weight in kg`);
  }

  // And let's not give people infinite precision, two
  // digits after the decimal point should be plenty.
  BMI.textContent = (w / (h/100) ** 2).toFixed(2);
});
<!--
  there is no form here, we don't need to send any sort
  of data to a server, we're just doing on-page calculation.
-->     

<div>
  <label for="height">Please input your height:</label>
  <input id="height" placeholder="height in cm">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="weight">Please input your weight:</label>
  <input id="weight" placeholder="weight in kg">
</div>

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>

<h3>Your BMI is: <span id="BMI"></span></h3>




I think you need to change from:
document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerText = answer;

to:
document.getElementById("result").innerText = answer;

And later in your HTML change to:
<p id="result"></p>

But, if you really need class in your p tag, use in your JS:
document.querySelector(".result").innerText = answer;

See the docs about querySelector.

prefer using id="result" in place of class in p tag
and in js function :
document.getElementById("result")

then you can use any of these :
    answer.innerHTML=BMI;
    answer.innerText=BMI;
    answer.textContent=BMI;

if you want class="result" then prefer
 document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML=BMI;

as getElementByClass selector selects all the classes have classname="result":
for more details check code:
<form>
  <label for="height">Please input your height in cms:</label>
  <input id="height" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="height" />
  <label for="weight">Please input your weight in kgs:</label>
  <input id="weight" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="weight" />
  <button onclick="BMIcalc()" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<h3>Your BMI is:</h3>
<p id="result"></p>
  

let myHeight = document.getElementById("height");
  let myWeight = document.getElementById("weight");
  let answer = document.getElementById("result");

  function BMIcalc() {
    if (myHeight.value === "" || myWeight.value === "") {
      alert("Please fill in your height and weight!");
    } else {
      const BMI = myWeight.value*100*100 / (myHeight.value * myHeight.value);
      answer.innerHTML=BMI;
    }
  }



getElementsByClassName returns a collection (similar to an array) of elements that match the specified class name. It does not return a single element directly.
You're trying to set innerHTML directly on the collection returned by getElementsByClassName. This won't work because getElementsByClassName returns multiple elements, and you need to update each one individually.

You need some refactoring in your code:

To solve this, you should iterate over the collection returned by getElementsByClassName and update the innerHTML of each element individually.



function bmiCalc() {
  let myheight = document.getElementById("height").value;
  let myweight = document.getElementById("weight").value;

  if (myheight === "" || myweight === "") {
    alert("Please Enter number........")
  } else {
    let ans = myheight / myweight ** 2;
    let resultElements = document.getElementsByClassName("result");
    for (let i = 0; i < resultElements.length; i++) {
      resultElements[i].innerHTML = "The BMI is: " + ans;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("height").value = "";
  document.getElementById("weight").value = "";
}
<input type="number" id="height" name="height" placeholder="Enter your height" />
<input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="Enter your weight" />
<button type="button" value="submit" onclick="bmiCalc()">Submit</button>
<p class="result">Pending....</p>




To solve this, you should iterate over the collection returned by getElementsByClassName and update the innerHTML of each element individually. <--- No, no, no, no, no. Use querySelectorAll() and stop using getElementsByClassName() especially looping over its live node list.

Additionally, avoid innerHTML when the string doesn't contain any HTML as innerHTML has performance and security implications. Use textContent instead.

Have a careful look at the HTML. There is only the one element with class result so why pursue the collections route?
